# How can i get response of a microservice in spring cloud gateway: and after getting that pass it to another microservice

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, api-gateway, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I do not want to use feign or rest template.

My scenario is:
i need to get the JWT token from auth service then pass it to the order cancellation service. I do not want that user add the returned token rather i want to get the token in api gateway and then call other services

Comment: question is not clear. What you mean by token in the api gateway and then call other services? Please explain the scenario!

Comment: Have you looked at spring cloud security? It has examples of how to do that